# How many ways can a lambda expression return the input immediately?

Tags: java, lambda

Say I want to transform a `Set<Foo>` to a `Map<Integer, Foo>` where the key corresponds to `Foo.hashCode()` I would normally implement it as follows:

```
Set<Foo> set = ...;
Map<Integer, Foo> map = set.stream()
                           .collect( Collectors.toMap( Object::hashCode, 
                                                       element -> element )
                                   );
```

Are there other ways to express `element -> element` in Java? If so, what are they?

Comment: (Just to check: do you actually expect your elements to have 100% unique hash codes?)

Comment: @LouisWasserman for the sake of argument, yes. I just picked an example that involved a simple transform. I understand that equal hashcodes do not imply equal objects in real life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Function.identity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--)

```
Map<Integer, Foo> map = list.stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                Object::hashCode, 
                                Function.identity()));
```

You can import that statically, then you'd have

```
Map<Integer, Foo> map = list.stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                Object::hashCode,
                                identity()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Function.identity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--) which does the same.